# Receiving and returning a packet after the function has ended

Tags: python, sockets, udp, packet

I have two functions. One sends a UDP packet to a port number and returns the port number if it gets a response. The second cycles through addresses calling the first function repeatedly incrementing the port number. It stops when a port number is returned. I'm basically spamming an IP to find which port number is being used.

All works well with very long time outs but I'm trying to speed up the rate at which I send my test packets. For example I might get a packet back from port 27018 even though the spam port function is sending to 27022. It then incorrectly reports that 27022 is the port to use. This happens even when I return the returned packet info from the first function since you can't tell the arguments which were used originally.

```
def check_port(s, serverip, serverport):  
    payload = "ffffffff54536f7572636520456e67696e6520517565727900".decode('hex')
    s.sendto(payload, (serverip, serverport))
    while 1:

        try:
            s.settimeout(0.1) # time to wait for response
            d = s.recvfrom(1400)
            data = d[0]
            addr = d[1]
            if len(data) > 1:
                break
        except socket.error:
            return False
    return addr[1]

def spam_ports(serverip): 
    s = serverComms.port_config()

    start_highport = 27015
    end_highport = 28015
    start_lowport = 2299
    end_lowport = 4000
    port = start_highport

    while check_port(s,serverip, port) == False:

        port += 1

        if port == end_highport:
            port = start_lowport
        if port == end_lowport:
           return 'no query ports found in range'

    else:
        return check_port(s,serverip, port)
```

I really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what happens.

It takes some time for the server to reply. If the delay is shorter than that, your application becomes confused. Let me explain:

You send packages to port 1000, 1001, 1002, ...

Say port 1010 produces a reply. But lets assume the server needs a full second to reply. Your application has progressed well bejond 1010 since the timeout is less then a second. By the time the reply arrives your application is already at, say, 1020. Now it looks like the received package is the result of sending something to 1020.

### Possible approch

What you need is a way to know to which port a received reply belongs. Here it gets tricky:

Each package has a source and a destination port. With the packages you send the destination port is incremented. The source port is probably arbitrarly assigned. When the server answers it will send a package with an arbitrary source port and the destination port equal the source port of your package.

What you could do is check with the documentation and see how you can control the source port of the packages you're sending. With that you make sure that each sent package has a different source port. This identifies each package uniquely. Now you can use the destination port of the reply to know were it belongs to.

Then you can use, for example, two threads. One sending out packages and one receiving the answers. You keep a dict that maps `my_source_port` to `server_port`. The sender fills the dict and the receiver reads it. You can let the sender send as fast as it can, now timeout required. Once the sender is done you give the receiver thread a second or so to catch up.

```
port_map = {}
active_ports = []

def send(min, max):
    for dest_port in range(min,max):
        src_port = get_free_port()
        port_map[src_port] = dest_port
        send_package(src_port, dest_port, 'somedata')

def recv():
    while True:
        src_port, dest_port, data = receive_package()
        port = port_map[dest_port]
        active_ports.append(port)
```

This is not a working example, just the basic idea. The methods don't exist in that form, thread synchronization is missing and `recv()` would run forever, but it shows the basic idea.

You probably have to create a socket for each package you send.